# Dispose of TFS server connection from C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, tfs, connection

I'm trying to connect and disconnect from a TFS server through a C# application. I'm able to connect using this method,

`TfsConfigurationServer ConfigurationServer = TfsConfigurationServerFactory.GetConfigurationServer(new Uri(serverString));`

but I'm unsure what to use to disconnect from the server. I currently using

`ConfigurationServer.Dispose()`

but I'm unsure if this just disposes of the object, or the connect itself. I'm trying to close the connection itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you may see, the Dispose() method is inherited from the [TfsConnection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.client.tfsconnection(v=vs.120).aspx) class, which implements IDisposable. Technically, that means that when Dispose() method is called on a TfsConfigurationServer object, the underlying TfsConnection will close.

To be sure, you can just check if the connection is still open right after you call Dispose(), by calling a Get*() method on your TfsConfigurationServer object.

As there is no Close() method on TfsConnection class, the Dispose() method is the only way to close a connection.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is no either `disconnect()` or `close()` method in TFS connection class.

.NET Garbage collector  or use **Dispose** method, this will close the connection.

Please read the description of TfsConnection class -- especially the method Dispose [TfsConnection.Dispose](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.client.tfsconnection.aspx) Method

You could refer related examples here: [Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TfsConnection.Dispose()](https://www.csharpcodi.com/csharp-examples/Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TfsConnection.Dispose()/)

> **Note:** When you disconnect from source control, you are not able to see the source control status of files or access source control
> functions.

Also take a look at this similar question: [Service running out of TCP connections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18666617/service-running-out-of-tcp-connections)